# The SystemMediaTransportControls were initialized in a different mode error in mytoolkit

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1-universal, mytoolkit

When i run mytoolkit after background audio player start is return "The SystemMediaTransportControls were initialized in a different mode.  Please use the API associated with that mode to complete this operation" Exception.

```
var url = await MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(ID, MyToolkit.Multimedia.YouTubeQuality.Quality480P);
```

it works fine when background audio player not started. please help me i cant find where is the error, is there any solution for that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code for background audio player use

```
var systemMediaControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
            systemMediaControls.ButtonPressed += systemMediaControls_ButtonPressed;
            systemMediaControls.IsPlayEnabled = true;
            systemMediaControls.IsPauseEnabled = true;
            systemMediaControls.IsNextEnabled = true;
            systemMediaControls.IsPreviousEnabled = true;

async void systemMediaControls_ButtonPressed(SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Button)
        {
            case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Play:
            break;
        }
    }
```

instead of

```
MediaControl.PlayPressed += MediaControl_PlayPressed;
             MediaControl.PausePressed += MediaControl_PausePressed;
```

Control.
I think it will help for you..

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the directions as [this guy](http://sonofabit.tumblr.com/post/88452710046/the-systemmediatransportcontrols-were-initialized) did for windows 8 and not for 8.1?

"Do NOT use the MediaControl static class to attach handlers for you Windows 8.1 app or you will get the error message"